# fillna() only fills the 1st value of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm facing a strange issue in which I'm trying to replace all NaN values in a dataframe with values taken from another one (same length) that has the relevant values.

Here's a glimpse for the "target dataframe" in which I want to replace the values:
`data_with_null`

[image: ![enter image description here]

Here's the dataframe where I want to take data from: `predicted_paticipant_groups`

[image]

I've tried:

`data_with_null.participant_groups.fillna(predicted_paticipant_groups.participant_groups, inplace=True)`

but it just fills all values NaN values with the 1st one (Infra)

[image]

Is it because of the indexes of `data_with_null` are all zeros?

Comment: As dfs are same length, have you tried merging them and running gillan on a single df?

Comment: `.fillna()` just takes a single value and replaces all NaN values with that. You probably just want to overwrite the `participant_groups` like so, no need to use `fillna` here: `df['participant_groups'] = df.predicted_paticipant_groups`?

Comment: You can use `data_with_null["participant_groups"]=predicted_paticipant_groups["participant_groups"].values`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the index and try again.

```
data_with_null.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: BTW, I'm still getting a warning 'Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:4529: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame'

Comment: You can learn more about that warning here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: I've also tried this: ```data_with_null = pd.merge(data_with_null, predicted_paticipant_groups, on='participant_groups')``` but I ended up with empty dataframe